# open graph image tag is working with like button but not working in direct share

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am facing the issue regarding sharing on Facebook in this link : http://www.voiceamerica.com/channel/247/voiceamerica-business here if i am sharing through like button then og:image is working fine but if i try to share same link with Bookmarks or direct link on Facebook then it is not fetching correct image from og:image tag. its picking random image.
[VoiceaMerica](http://www.voiceamerica.com/channel/247/voiceamerica-business)

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Comment: HI tristanm,I found the solution for sharing link with images,size of image should be minimum 200x200

Answer (score 0):

Debug your URL with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ this will show you if there is something wrong with your tags.